# Apps Script - Add students to all Google Classrooms in a domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I want to add a single student to all of the Google Classrooms in my domain.

I am a super admin of the domain and am able to add a single student to a classroom that I know the id of but I want to force the addition of the student to all classrooms.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: Welcome. The question misses to include a brief description of the search/research efforts. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: I would suggest checking [Enroll or remove students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#enroll_or_remove_students) as it teaches you, as an admin, to enroll students using [courses.students.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create).